# Error in creating an array of even numbers

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop

I don't know where am I doing wrong in this code.
 I wanted to create an array of even nos. so I wrote the following code in matlab:

```
A=[];
n=2;
while n!=5
     if n%2==0
       A=[A n];
       n++;
     else
       n++;
     end
end
 disp(A)
```

The following gets displayed as output:

```
2   3   4
```

I can't understand why all nos. between 1 to 5 are being displayed.
can anyone please explain where am I wrong.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know where am I doing wrong in this code.

1. In MATLAB, the not-equal-to operator is `~=`; `!=` is invalid MATLAB syntax.
2. If you want to increment a variable `n`, you need to write `n = n + 1`; `n++` is invalid MATLAB syntax.
3. The `%` character starts a line comment; it is *not* the modulo operator. Instead, you want to use either the `rem` function or the `mod` function (which are equivalent for nonnegative inputs).

Besides, you don't need a loop for creating such a simple row vector, in which elements follow an arithmetic sequence. Just use MATLAB's [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
<start> : <step> : <bound>
```

or, more simply

```
<start> : <bound>
```

where the step is taken as `1`.

Here, either

```
2:2:8
```

or

```
2 * (1 : 4)
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going wrong very early.  Try this

```
A = 2:2:8
```

then go to the Matlab documentation and read about the `colon` operator.  Then forget C and C++ (what's with all those `n++` and the other syntax elements from foreign languages ?).  Then forget about loops and learn about *vectorisation*, you'll get a lot more out of Matlab, with a lot less effort, that way.